# images in 3d text

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, 3d

[image: logo]

I am making this logo and I'm trying to get my colorful block image throughout my 3d text instead of just on the front of it. Anyone know of a way to do that? help pleaasse!

Comment: Or is there an easier way of doing it in another program?

Answer (score 1):

This is not easy in Illustrator. You can map multiple sides, but lining them up so your grid image is perfect? -- Very hard. Basically there's no easy way. This would be easier if done manually instead of using the 3d filter.

Comment: how would I do it manually?